# pégar imagem e gravar no banco de dados sql no campo image

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Boa tarde.
Estou com um probleminha no meu código e preciso de uma ajuda. Estou inserindo uma imagem no meu form em um campo imagem, agora preciso pegar esta imagem e gravar em um campo no sql server um campo image. Como posso realizar esta gravação.

segue abaixo meu código onde busco a imagem no pc e jogo no Form.

```
 private void btn_imagem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        open_imagem.FileName = "";
        open_imagem.Title = "Imagem do Chamdo";
        open_imagem.Filter = "JPEG | *.JPG | PNG | *.PNG";
        open_imagem.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void open_imagem_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        pcb_imagem.Image = Image.FromFile(open_imagem.FileName);
    }
```

Agora segue o código de insert.

```
 public String cadchamado(String usuario, String departamento, String tipo, String comentario, DateTime data)
    {
        if (usuario != "")
        {
            tem = false;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_chamados values(@GM_USUARIO, @GM_DEPARTAMENTO, @GM_TIPO, @GM_COMENTARIO, @GM_DTINICIAL)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GM_USUARIO", usuario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GM_DEPARTAMENTO", departamento);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GM_TIPO", tipo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GM_COMENTARIO", comentario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GM_DTINICIAL", data);
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = con.conectar();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.desconectar();
                this.mensagem = "Chamado incluído com sucesso!!";
                tem = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                throw;

                //this.mensagem = "Erro ao inserir chamado verifique!!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.mensagem = "Existem campos em branco por favor preencer, obrigado!!";
        }
        return mensagem;
    }
```

Desde já agradesço

Comment: O winforms é C#?

Comment: sim tenho um form em c#

Comment: Sou do mundo java e trabalho com banco sql server, acredito que o conceito seja o mesmo. Esse tipo de dado (image) se mapeia na sua classe como byte array (byte[]). Então acredito que vc precisará transformar esse arquivo em um byte[] e depois salvar. Veja esses exemplos, creio que te ajudará: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/736961/Save-file-in-sql-database-in-csharp-win-form

Comment: Gravar imagens no banco de dados é uma péssima ideia... No seu insert não vejo o parâmetro para o blob da imagem... atualize a sua pergunta mostrando como você está fazendo e onde está encontrando o erro. [MCVE]

Comment: Ok obrigado pela ajuda Adriano Gomes, consegui fazer a gravação.

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro Então seria interessante você postar a resposta com a sua solução ou fechar a pergunta